# Update payload to change true to True

Tags: python

I have this payload:

```
payload = {"data":{"horse_name": "beauty", "horse_id":"52", "is_manual":true }}
```

This returns:

```
> NameError: name 'true' is not defined
```

...which is correct.

How to change the above payload to make it `True` so it looks like:

```
payload = {"data":{"horse_name": "beauty", "horse_id":"52", "is_manual":True }}
```

Comment: Where is the payload coming from? If it is JSON then you need to use `json.loads()` to convert it to a dict, which will automatically handle that for you.

Comment: "How to change the above payload to make it True so it looks like" By... editing the code and replacing the lowercase t with an uppercase T? The `NameError` indicates that the line in question is literally part of your code. Did you perhaps mean for `payload` to be a string, and then to parse that string as JSON? You need to explain more about what you're doing, specifically what problem you're trying to solve, and what "payload" means to you.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, hmm, this could work as well if I can get what I want. Lack of Python experience is a current problem.